# Connecting a solidity smart contract to streamlit

Tags: python, solidity, streamlit

first post here. Can anyone help with fixing this argument issue. I must say that this is for a class project and this will never be put to use for monetary gain.

I am making a makeshift NFT marketplace through Streamlit. My contract is as follows:

```
contract Top10NFL is ERC721Full {
    constructor() public ERC721Full("Top10NFLtoken", "TOP") {}
    function mintToken(address NFT_Owner, string memory tokenURI, uint256 tokenIDinput) public payable returns (uint256) {
      uint256 tokenID = tokenIDinput;
      _mint(NFT_Owner, tokenID);
      _setTokenURI(tokenID, tokenURI);
      return tokenID;
    }
}
```

This is the connection point to call the contract:

```
import os
import json
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from web3 import Web3
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from streamlit_player import st_player


   st.title("Play 10 - Philly Special - Eagles vs Patriots")
    st_player("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3Jqif1TUwQ")

    if st.button("Buy Philly Special NFT"):
        play_10_uri = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3Jqif1TUwQ"

        tx_hash = contract.functions.mintToken(
            address,
            play_10_uri,
        ).transact({"from": address, "value": offer_price*1000000000000000000, "gas": 2000000})
        receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
        st.write("Transaction receipt mined:")
        st.write(dict(receipt))
```

This worked just fine the other day and nothing was changed but now I am unable to get it work correctly. I believe that my if statement only has two arguments in it while the mint function calls for three. Reason for this current error.

```
ValidationError: Could not identify the intended function with name `mintToken`, positional argument(s) of type `(<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>)` and keyword argument(s) of type `{}`. Found 1 function(s) with the name `mintToken`: ['mintToken(address,string,uint256)'] Function invocation failed due to improper number of arguments.
```

Removing an argument from the contract will not let it compile. I am not sure what to add to the if statement if anything at all.
Thank you.

Comment: Question needs working code:
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  ,  what is `st`, what is `st_player` etc...

Comment: Edited to show all imports, st_player is the function that allows streamlit to add videos.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your question yourself, there is one input argument missing.
it needs some integer for the tokenId

```
tx_hash = contract.functions.mintToken(
        address,
        play_10_uri,
        tokenId
    )
```